# What does a throttle valve actuator do in carburetors?

Tags: engine-theory, part-identification, carburetor, throttle, actuator

i tried looking online but could not find much information about throttle valve actuators in carburetors. I think they look like this part in the picture below circled in red. What is the purpose of this part?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The carburetor you have an image of is a Quadrajet carb. What you have circled is the choke vacuum diaphram. There is also an electric version of this. It (as the name implies) is an automatic actuator for the choke. The choke helps with fuel enrichment when the engine is cold. Some carburetor manufacturers do things differently.

Here is a diagram which breaks out the external parts of this carburetor:

[image]

Comment: I see thanks, also its actually Solex 4A1 carburetor that i posted in the picture. It was used in lot of european cars during 1970s. Maybe the reason i could not find anything was because of the name difference as you said. Its called Drosselklappenansteller in German and most translation sites translate it as "throttle valve actuator". https://www.senatorman.de/vergaser_4a1.htm found it here, this site is written in german and google translated "Drosselklappenansteller" as throttle valve actuator instead of choke vacuum diapghram

Comment: Also a video showing that part on solex 4a1 https://www.youtube.com/shorts/doH4msElHF8

Comment: @TimothyScherer - Well, it makes sense, because the Solex carb is a copy of the Rochester Quadrajet carb. It appears [Solex manufactured them under license from Rochester](http://www.peachparts.com/shopforum/3521473-post11.html). That link also states they both suffered from a lot of the same problems, which would also make sense.

Comment: @TimothyScherer - To be quite fair to the Google Translation, what you used is *exactly* what it does ... just the term for it comes down to something a little different. (IOW: It's all good!)

Comment: ♦ Oh i see thanks, i didnt realize solex 4a1 was copy of the quadrajet.

Comment: Some automatic chokes used a curved [bimetallic strip](https://www.google.co.uk/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.aa1car.com%2Flibrary%2Fcarburetor_choke_operation.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.aa1car.com%2Flibrary%2Fcarburetor.htm&tbnid=zFDkKei95PklPM&vet=12ahUKEwjLtK7ryrv9AhUomycCHck-B8wQMygHegQIARBS..i&docid=FWb5BdzCuB-JvM&w=640&h=480&q=carburetor%20choke%20curved%20bimetallic%20strip&ved=2ahUKEwjLtK7ryrv9AhUomycCHck-B8wQMygHegQIARBS) to control it.